# Splitting strings and unscrambling them

Tags: c, string, split, token

I have an assignment that requires us to split a string and unscramble it. For example:

"rsedreve*_*emth*_*kema*_*ot*_*si*_*skta*_*uryo"

becomes:
"Your task is to make them reversed."

So far for code, I have just splitting the string:

```
 char secondString[50];

 char *secondString_ptr;

 strcpy(secondString, "rsedreve*_*emth*_*kema*_*ot*_*si*_*skta*_*uryo");

 secondString_ptr = strtok(secondString, "*_*");

 while(secondString_ptr != NULL){
            printf("%s ", secondString_ptr);
            secondString_ptr = strtok(NULL, "*_*");
    }
```

Output:

rsedreve emth kema ot si skta uryo

Obviously, the pattern here is to start at half the length of these tokens, add these characters to a char[] and then add the characters at the beginning of each tokens to the end. Can someone help me out and show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As you have split the string, you need to unscramble them.  I think the easiest way to unscramble this is to swap the appropriate letters.

So you find the middle, then swap with the beginning and so on.  For example, if you have "123456", you swap 1 and 4, then 2 and 5, then 3 and 6.

Here is a basic function that could do this:

```
char* unscramble(char *input)
{
        int len = strlen(input);
        int half = len >> 1;
        int i;
        for (i=0 ;i<half; i++)
        {
                int temp = input[i];
                input[i] = input[half+i];
                input[half+i] = temp;
        }
        return input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than simply printing each token, find the length of the token, do the unscrambling, shove it onto a stack, and print it out in reverse.

**Edit: edited to be less of a complete solution but rather helpful snippets.**

You can use an array, for example, as a simple 'stack'

```
    char *pseudoStack[MAX_WORDS];
    int stackPos = 0;
```

Add to the stack like this

```
    pseudoStack[stackPos] = unscrambled;
    stackPos++;
```

And print like this

```
    for (i = stackPos - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%s ", pseudoStack[i]);
        free(pseudoStack[i]);
    }
```

Unscrambling can be done in precisely the manner you described. Don't forget to malloc so that you don't change the original string and so that you can keep the string after the loop ends.

```
        char *unscrambled = malloc(MAX_WORD_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
        int unscrambledPos = 0;
        for (i = middle; i < wordLength; i++) {
            unscrambled[unscrambledPos] = secondString_ptr[i];
            unscrambledPos++;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < middle; i++) {
            unscrambled[unscrambledPos] = secondString_ptr[i];
            unscrambledPos++;
        }
        unscrambled[wordLength] = '\0';
```

Also don't forget the null character at the end!

While it's rather verbose, at least this way you can see the reasoning in each step.

Is there a policy on stackoverflow about homework questions though...?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
    char secondString[50];
    char *secondString_ptr;
    int i,j,n,stack_pointer=0;
    char *Word;
    char *stack[50];
    strcpy(secondString, "rsedreve*_*emth*_*kema*_*ot*_*si*_*skta*_*uryo");

    secondString_ptr = strtok(secondString, "*_*");

    while(secondString_ptr != NULL){
            n=strlen(secondString_ptr);
            Word=(char *)malloc(n);
       /*the second half and the first half form the meaningful word*/
       /*so split the word into two part and assign to the variable. Like this*/
            for(i=n/2,j=0;i<n;i++)
                    Word[j++]=secondString_ptr[i];
            for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
                    Word[j++]=secondString_ptr[i];
            Word[j]='\0';
       /*put all this word in the stack and increment the pointer*/
            secondString_ptr = strtok(NULL, "*_*");
    }
    stack[stack_pointer]=NULL;
    for(i=stack_pointer-1;i>=0;i--)
            printf("%s ",stack[i]);
     printf("\n");
```

}

This is the algorithm for your requirement.

Comment: This helped in my understanding I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int unscrambling(char *str){
    char *p = strtok(str, "*_");
    if(p){
        char temp[50];
        int len = strlen(p);
        int len1 = len >> 1;
        int len2 = len - len1;
        //char temp[len2];
/*
        memcpy(temp, p, len2);
        memcpy(p, p+len2, len1);
        memcpy(p+len1, temp, len2);
*/
        memcpy(temp, p, len1);
        memcpy(p, p+len1, len2);
        memcpy(p+len2, temp, len1);
        if(unscrambling(NULL))
            *p = toupper(*p);
        if(str)
            printf("%s.\n", p);
        else
            printf("%s ", p);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    char string[50];

    strcpy(string, "rsedreve*_*emth*_*kema*_*ot*_*si*_*skta*_*uryo");
    unscrambling(string);
    strcpy(string, "rsedreve*_emth_*kema*_ot_*si*_skta_*uryo");
    unscrambling(string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Was able to modify it to split the string on any character I wanted. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: By the way, this algorithm will only work if the word you are trying to unscramble had an even number of characters. If it something like "without" which has 7 it will output "ithoutw".

Comment: @user3268401 It was assumed to be the "houtwit" --> "without" because there was no example in the case of odd. Try to fix.

Comment: I did fix it. Added this after "int len = strlen(p);"  :

int temp1 = len % 2;
int len1;
if(temp1)
     len1 = (len >> 1) + 1;
else
     len1 = len >> 1;

Comment: @user3268401 It is OK in your way. No problem.